# RegEx for extracting the first occurrence of domains

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a list of domain on each line like this

```
www.google.dk/

www.google.dk/

www.google.com/

www.google.de/

www.google.dk/

www.google.dk/
```

I want only first occurence of each domain like this:

```
www.google.dk/

www.google.com/

www.google.de/
```

I´ve look everywhere with similar topics but cannot get something that works for me.

Comment: Why you not find an easier solution to your problem, e.g. not using regex?

Comment: Put these domains in a set and then just get it back from set. Set only contains unique elements and hence will remove the duplicate ones.

Comment: You know about [`uniq(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html)?

Comment: It has to be Regex because its inside another program and that is the only solution- sorry

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh - Really a newbie on regex - could you show how to do that?

Comment: Which tools/language do you use ? Regex depend on it... And this tool/language will surely provide things to resolve this simpler than by using regex (like with a Set)

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx should work for you.

(?<=www.)[a-z.0-9]+(?=/)|(?<=https://)[a-z.0-9]+(?=/)|(?<=http://)[a-z.0-9]+(?=/)|^[a-z.0-9]+(?=/)

To explain I will break it in to parts.

1. positive lookbehind - (?<=) / (?<= "here is what you are looking for" )
2. positive look for lowercase letters, dots and digits in any occurrences [a-z.0-9]+
3. positive lookahead - (?=) / (?= "here is what you are looking for" )
4. or - |

lookbehind for "www."
(?<=www.)

match any occurrences of lowercase letters, dots and digits  between the  "www." and "/"
[a-z.0-9]+

lookahead for "/"
(?=/)

or
|

after that things go the same way I am changing just the values for the lookbehind

I hope I have helped.

[image]

Comment: Please add some explanation to that expression. How exactly does it handle the case of multiple occurences?

Comment: Ok, I will break it in to parts.
• Positive lookbehind - (?<=) / (?<= "here is what you are looking for" ) 
• Positive look for lowercase letters, dots and digits in any occurrences [a-z.0-9]+
•  Positive lookahead - (?=) / (?= "here is what you are looking for" )  or - |
• or - |

• lookbehind for "www."
(?<=www.)

• match any occurrences of lowercase letters, dots and digits  between the  "www." and "/"       
[a-z.0-9]+

• lookahead for "/"
(?=/)

• or
|

after that things go the same way I am changing just the values for the lookbehind

Comment: Please add all such information to the answer itself, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

If it does not have the be the *first* match, but can also be the *last* match (i.e. you just need the unique domain), you could use a negative lookahead with the matching group again.

```
([^\n]+)(?!.*\1)
```

(Using `([^\n]+)` to match a domain, using the fact that each domain is on a single line; you could also use a more complex domain-matching regex in this place.)

[Regex-101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MoTHJP/1)

```
www.google.dk/
www.google.dk/
www.google.com/  match
www.google.de/   match
www.google.dk/
www.google.dk/   match
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, this kind of task should be easily done using code, like I described in my comment above, that put all your URLs in a `Set` collection which would eliminate all the duplicates and then just iterate the `Set` to get your unique URLs.

But if due to some limitation you need a pure regex solution then you can use this regex,

```
(\S+)(?![\w\W]*\1)
```

which will capture duplicate URLs only once, because this URL essentially captures the last string among the duplicate ones.

**Regex Explanation:**

- `(\S+)` - Capture the URL using `\S+` because URLs can't contain spaces within themselves
- `(?![\w\W]*\1)` - And this negative lookahead ensures that the captured string in group1 is no longer seen anywhere ahead using back reference `\1` and `[\w\W]` is a way of matching any character including newline, although you could achieve same using a dot but then you need to enable `DOTALL` mode either by placing `(?s)` at start of regex or by passing an extra argument flag in the choice of your language if it supports one.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R7T74Q/1/)**